# HTML5 Javascript function not getting called on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page, thats intended to take user's email and password. I defined "login()" method in one of js file but the function doesn't get executed after button click.

HTML file:
http://pastie.org/10276940

Comment: Please create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Check if this function is available to call from this html file. Add alert('hello') to function and call it directly without parameters like  onclick="Login()". It's likely that this function is declared after html is rendered. (for example in window.load event). If it is being called then you know that problem is with function itself and you should debug it to a place where your code fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

first, you should be careful about quotes and double quotes... there is already a mistake in your onclick code.

Then, I would not use onclick. I would do it by adding an eventListener (click) on the button, like this :

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click',function(){
    //do something
});
```

Here is an example on this way to do it.
There are several other ways to do this, like you did with onClick, but here is just the way I would do the job.

http://jsfiddle.net/tz4bnu0m/4/

Problem is also that when you call login in your onclick event, function is just not defined (yet), here is a way to do it with your onclick event, just add function definition before you call it in onclick event :

http://jsfiddle.net/tz4bnu0m/5/

Hope it helps!

(since it is not an input type submit, you don't have to handle default action, click will not submit the form by default)

Comment: I think the issue in the code was double quote which u correctly pointed.

Comment: I am trying to open google page in the JS function using:  window.location = "http://www.google.com"; but its not working

Comment: the issue is the code open google page in new window, instead i need to open in same page         http://pastie.org/10277108  . I also tried using location.href or window.location.href

Answer (score -1):

The problem is on the button.

```
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" onclick="login(document.getElementById("inputEmail").value,
            document.getElementById("inputPassword").value)">Sign in</button>
```

You are  mixing double quotes. Change it by single quotes an it works

```
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" onclick="login(document.getElementById('inputEmail').value,
            document.getElementById('inputPassword').value)">Sign in</button>
```

This works but...
I don't recommend to you to make this events in HTML directly. You can separate this code and make it more reusable:

```
 <button id="myID"></button>
 <script>
     document.getElementById("myID").onclick = function() {
            // good stuff
     };

     //other way:
     document.getElementById("myID").addEventListener('click', function() {
             // good stuff
     });
 </script>
```

Good luck